# quote string for TeX input

Tags: python, string, tex, quoting

I am writing a Python script that takes plain text as input and produces
LaTeX code as output.  At some point the script has to quote all the
characters that have a special meaning in TeX, such as `%`, `&`, `\`, and so
on.

This is more difficult than I expected. Currently I have this:

```
def ltx_quote(s):
    s = re.sub(r'[\\]', r'\\textbackslash{}', s)
    # s = re.sub(r'[{]', r'\\{{}', s)
    # s = re.sub(r'[}]', r'\\}{}', s)
    s = re.sub(r'[&]', r'\\&{}', s)
    s = re.sub(r'[$]', r'\\${}', s)
    s = re.sub(r'[%]', r'\\%{}', s)
    s = re.sub(r'[_]', r'\\_{}', s)
    s = re.sub(r'[\^]', r'\\^{}', s)
    s = re.sub(r'[~]', r'\\~{}', s)
    s = re.sub(r'[|]', r'\\textbar{}', s)
    s = re.sub(r'[#]', r'\\#{}', s)
    s = re.sub(r'[<]', r'\\textless{}', s)
    s = re.sub(r'[>]', r'\\textgreater{}', s)
    return s
```

The problem is the `{` and `}` characters, because they are potentially produced by an earlier substitution (`\` -> `\textbackslash{}`) in which case shouldn't be substituted. I think the solution would be making all the substitutions in one step, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps try using the undocumented [re.Scanner](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-April/035075.html):

```
import re
scanner = re.Scanner([
    (r"[\\]", r'\\textbackslash{}'),
    (r"[{]", r'\\{{}'),
    (r"[}]", r'\\}{}'), 
    (r".", lambda s, t: t)
])

tokens, remainder = scanner.scan("\\foo\\{bar}")
print(''.join(tokens))
```

yields

```
\\textbackslash{}foo\\textbackslash{}\\{{}bar\\}{}
```

Unlike the code you posted, if you look at [the source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0f827775f7b7/Lib/re.py#l308), the re.Scanner.scan makes only **one pass** through the string. Once a match is made, the next match is begun from where the last match ended.

The first argument to `re.Scanner` is a `lexicon` -- a list of 2-tuples. Each 2-tuple is a regex pattern and an action. The action may be a string, a callable (function), or `None` (no action).

The patterns are all compiled into one compound pattern. So the order in which the patterns are listed in the lexicon is important. The first pattern to match wins.

If a match is made, the action is called if it is callable, or simply returned if a string. The return values are collected in the list `tokens`.